# MongoDb. Update any field if the value is negative

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5f7db1c8e3ec502bf2f2c97c",
  "subject": "AA0001",
  "metrics": {
     "m001": 40.8,
     "m0022": 58.8,
     .....
     "m0101: -5.0,
  }
}
```

All the fields inside "metrics" are numbers. The negative values are wrong. I want to replace any negative value with "NA". But I have two problems:

- The fields with negative values are different for each document.
- The fields inside "metrics" are not always the same. One document can have more "metrics" than other.

¿Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$objectToArray` to convert metrics object into an array of key-value pair objects and then `$map` it to transform the array in a way if the number is negative it will be replaced with "NA" using a condition operation. After doing the transformation you can convert the array back to an object using `$arrayToObject`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      metrics: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$metrics" },
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: { $cond: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.v", 0 ] }, "$$this.v", "NA" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      metrics: { $arrayToObject: "$metrics" }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wWha6EHuUPk)

you can also update the collection to reflect these changes. [Since Mongo 4.2 you can write aggregation pipeline inside `update` calls](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-update-many-method-agg-pipeline)

`$addFields` and `$set` can be used interchangeably

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      metrics: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$metrics" },
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: { $cond: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.v", 0 ] }, "$$this.v", "NA" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      metrics: { $arrayToObject: "$metrics" }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhIEHNx2E_I)

Comment: The pipeline works. But db.collection.aggregate does not update the collection. How will you use the pipeline inside db.collection.updateMany ?

Comment: @Juan can you try with https://mongoplayground.net/p/9OfDvpo4Vgh

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "metrics": { $exists: true } },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "metrics": {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$metrics" },
              in: {
                k: "$$this.k",
                v: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: { $lt: [ "$$this.v", 0 ] },
                    then: "NA",
                    else: "$$this.v"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```